# How pass to react list item to function as parameter at onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i wonder how i can pass as parameter to onClick function react list element

here is my list.

```
const items = this.state.tableData.items.map(
      (item, index) => <td key={index} onClick={this.getItem}>{item.name}</td>
    );
```

here is i define my function

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tableData: this.props.items
    };
    this.getItem = this.getItem.bind(this);

  }
```

here is my function.

```
 getItem(item) {
    console.log(item)
  }
```

I wan't to get item details onClick to item where i render my list.

i tried to make `onClick={this.getItem(item)}` i get with this way item details but not at onClick. Just all items details console logged when i open my page.

what can i do ?

Comment: Just use this : onClick={()=>this.getItem(params)}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two common ways: Using an arrow function, or using `bind`:

Arrow function:

```
const items = this.state.tableData.items.map(
  (item, index) => <td key={index} onClick={e => this.getItem(item, e)}>{item.name}</td>
);
```

`bind`:

```
const items = this.state.tableData.items.map(
  (item, index) => <td key={index} onClick={this.getItem.bind(this, item)}>{item.name}</td>
);
```

In both cases, with the above, `getItem` would get the item as its first argument, the event object as its second.

Answer (score 1):

This is just an alternative answer. Separating the `item` into its own component would be an alternative. In this way, you can pass the `onClick` function without binding it then use it in the `Item` component like this.

```js
const items = [{ id: 1, name: "foo" }, { id: 2, name: "bar" }];

const Item = ({ item, getItem}) => {
  const handleClick = () => getItem(item);
  return (
    <div onClick={handleClick}>{item.name}</div>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  const getItem = item => console.log(item.id);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {items.map(item => (
        <Item key={item.id} item={item} getItem={getItem} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

If there are so many `items` you can avoid rerendering all the items if none of their props changed since you don't use `bind` or any inline arrow function. But, as you can see it needs a separate component and some more coding.

Comment: Thank you it's interesting approach too

Answer (score 1):

Functional Components are going to win over classes.
So better to be used with this:

```
      onClick={  ( item.id) => handleclick( item.id, [...])
```

Edit 1
    Handleclick here intended as a Hook ( e. G.  SetValue on useState).

Nb:
     On purpose code dirty to fight against the awful copypasta SO practice. Thanks redditors. Read the code, then read the memes.